# XSLT add parent node name as element in child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

***Input***

```
<root>
    <category1>
        <node>
            <subnode>value</subnode>
        </node>
    </category1>

    <category2>
        <node>
            <subnode>value</subnode>
        </node>
    </category2>
</root>
```

***Output***

```
<root>
    <node>
        <subnode>value</subnode>
        </category1>
    </node>

    <node>
        <subnode>value</subnode>
        </category2>
    </node>
</root>
```

Or

```
<root>
    <node>
        <subnode>value</subnode>
        <status>category1</status>
    </node>

    <node>
        <subnode>value</subnode>
        <status>category2</status>
    </node>
</root>
```

***Attempt***

```
<xsl:template match="//node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
        <xsl:copy-of select=".." />
        <!--
        Why isn't something like this possible? 
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::local-name()"/> 
        -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

***Details***

Hopefully, the above was clear enough :).

---

---

***Additional Details (Optional)***

For those feeling especially generous this Christmas I invite you to continue reading :D.

I'm having some trouble learning XSLT and feel like I'm missing some general/syntactical concepts but I also need to do some 'complicated' transforms. For example:

***Input***

```
<root>
    <category1>
        <node>
            <name>category1 node pk</name>
        </node>
    </category1>

    <groups>
        <node>
            <name>First Group</name>
            <members>
                <name>category1 node pk</name>
            </members>
        </node>

        <node>
            <name>Second Group</name>
            <members>
                <name>category1 node pk</name>
            </members>
        </node>
    </groups>
</root>
```

***Output***

```
<root>
    <node>
        <name>category1 node pk</name>
        <group>All</group>
        <status>category1</status>
    </node>

    <node>
        <name>category1 node pk</name>
        <group>First Group</group>
        <status>category1</status>
    </node>

    <node>
        <name>category1 node pk</name>
        <group>Second Group</group>
        <status>category1</status>
    </node>
</root>
```

So for the XSLT experts out there what I would like to know is how you went about learning ***XSLT 1.0***? Especially to deal with more complicated transforms.

Are there any books or tutorials that you found especially useful?

Finally how long do you think it would take for someone new to become proficient enough to pull off the above transform w/o help?

Comment: How do you decide whether to output `<group>ALL</group>` or `<group>First Group</group>`?

Comment: Yea I should have been more clear. <group>All</group> is the default. What happening is that the node has to be duplicated for each group its in. Give me a second to modify my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly (XSLT code and output), i.e. to work with your updated input.

Answer (score 2):

the syntax for `<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::local-name()"/>` is `<xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>`. Slotting that in the full code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <status><xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/></status>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and gives you the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<node>
    <subnode>value</subnode>
    <status>category1</status>
</node>
<node>
    <subnode>value</subnode>
    <status>category2</status>
</node>
</root>
```

as required

Answer (score 1):

This should help you to get started. I am aware that your actual XML input is more complex than that, but this produces exactly the output you describe (for the look-at-this-if-you-are-feeling-generous part).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category1">
  <node>
     <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="node/name"/>
     </name>
     <group>
        <xsl:text>ALL</xsl:text>
     </group>
     <status>
        <xsl:text>category1</xsl:text>
     </status>
  </node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="groups">
  <xsl:for-each select="node">
     <node>
        <name>
           <xsl:value-of select="members/name"/>
        </name>
        <group>
           <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </group>
        <status>
           <xsl:text>category1</xsl:text>
        </status>
     </node>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node>
    <name>category1 node pk</name>
    <group>ALL</group>
    <status>category1</status>
 </node>

 <node>
    <name>category1 node pk</name>
    <group>First Group</group>
    <status>category1</status>
 </node>
 <node>
  <name>category1 node pk</name>
  <group>Second Group</group>
  <status>category1</status>
 </node>
</root>
```

Now, to your question about learning XSLT. If you meant books on the subject, Michael Kay's "Programmers Reference for XSLT 2.0 and XPATH" is by far the best resource if you do not mind technical details. See for example here: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764569090.html.

Comment: Would this book be okay for 1.0? I need to learn 1.0 because from what I've seen most browsers have not implement 2.0. and I'm working in GWT/Javascript :).

Comment: Yes - for the most part, it's the same. The quality of the book outweighs the differences between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, so to say. But, as I said, it is technical in style which might prove difficult if this is your first encounter with programming.

Comment: Its just my first encounter with XSLT :D but thanks for the recommendation